# Why testing should not continue when defect has critical priority?

Tags: testing, theory

I am trying to understand a testing theory and few times I have seen following, which is related to priority:

```
1. Critical : Bugs at this level must be resolved as soon as possible. Testing
should not progress until a known critical defect is fixed.
```

or

```
1.Immediate fix, blocks further testing, very visible
```

But to be honest, I dont know why. Why could I not test e.g. another part of the system until the critical-priority bug has been fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I expect the reason behind this design is that these bugs intend to mark massive interdependencies of the critical parts with other parts of your system.

For example, if you have an application that deals with money pervasively, you may have a test at the base of your system that determines whether currencies are represented accurately. If they aren't, and you keep testing other parts of your system, you may find other numerical tests that report wrong results elsewhere. Unfortunately, **you may also waste time** looking for an error in your math or your algorithm, and spend time fixing those numerical tests while, in fact, **they're doing the Right thing with the wrong currency**.

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to test something else, then the bug is not priority/severity 1. Simple as that. :-) Priority 1 bugs tend to be things like "code does not compile" or "the system crashes at bootup and there is no workaround".